# Serious word for 'a bad guy'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, formality

I was trying to raise awareness of XSS attacks on a website, by launching a harmless XSS attack and showing the follow message if users fell for it:

> IT WAS AN XSS ATTACK!
>
> HAD IT BEEN MADE BY A BAD GUY, YOUR ACCOUNT WOULD HAVE BEEN STOLEN.

I want my message to sound serious, but 'a bad guy' seems informal. I quickly Googled a list of synonyms, but, as a non-native speaker, couldn't figure out which fits more in this content. Can you provide suggestions?

<sup>Well, maybe I should tell my professor his site is flawed directly.</sup>

Comment: Well, there's always "malefactor".  And that word likely has a bunch of synonyms, if you look.  In fact -- wrongdoer, miscreant, offender, criminal, culprit, villain, lawbreaker, felon, evildoer, delinquent, hooligan, hoodlum.

Comment: You know, the trend these days is to use plain and informal language for user messages. I have noticed Google in particular doing that. I think "bad guy" is okay. _This was an XSS attack. If I had been a bad guy, I could have stolen your account._

Comment: Making an XSS attack on a website that shows people that message without consent is still likely a crime. The responsible and legal way to deal with the situation would be to tell the website owner directly about the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would change the wording to refer more to the attack than the person.

"Had it been malicious, your account would have been stolen."

Comment: Excellent point. I couldn't put my finger on why using a noun here felt... somehow wrong. Adjective is the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

**Attacker** fits the tone of rest of the message, and in prticular the use of the word attack. By adding **real** or **actual** you can differentiate yourself from the "bad guy" since you are technically using the vulnerability yourself.

**Malicious user** can be an alternative, since it directly describes the bad behavior.

**Adversary** is often used in infosec, but is typically used in a more hypothetical and technical tone and might not fit you warning message.

> The site has an XSS vulnerability. An adversary could execute
>   client-side code under conditions X and Y.

Answer (score 3):

I think people understand **hacker** in this context.

> Had it been made by a hacker, your account would have been stolen.

Comment: Wasn't it made by a hacker in any case? (Albeit one with good intentions.)

Comment: In the software field, there's a difference between the word "hacker" and "cracker", the latter being the black-hat type. I think it would be more correct to go with the other answer above, the one using the phrase "Had it been malicious..."

Comment: The Wikipedia entry for Hacker (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_(computer_security)) has Eric S. Raymond distinguishing crackers (underground) from hackers (ethical). However, in common parlance (which is what the OP is asking for), hackers carry a connotation of the "bad guys." @Zwi, can you cite any movies or books that portray the hacker as a "good guy"?

Comment: I currently work in the software field, @Zwi, and have worked in combating viruses and vulnerabilities. The term "hacker" *always* had a negative connotation.

Answer (score 1):

**Antagonist** or **real attacker** seem like they might work here.

Comment: Antagonist is generally used when referring to fiction. It sounds odd hearing people in real life referred to as antagonists.

Answer (score 1):

**irresponsibly**

> Had it be done *irresponsibly*, you would have lost your account.

Because of course it's an action

> done or said without thinking of the possible results of your actions
>   or words
>   [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/irresponsible#irresponsible_3)

It fits better for illegal attacks, though.